# Use low gc_grace_seconds when DELETE with consistency level ALL

Tags: cassandra, garbage-collection

If my Cassandra `DELETE` operations always use a consistency level of `ALL`, is it safe to reduce the `gc_grace_seconds` property to a low value? It seems to me that the `ALL` consistency level means that repairs of deletion operations are never necessary, so the safety provided by the GC grace period is unnecessary. Or are there corner cases that mean the GC grace period is still useful?

Comment: what happens if one of your nodes is down for > gc_grace_seconds or perhaps for > hinted_handoff duration (default 3 hours)? When that node comes back up, I think you might experience some zombie records.

Comment: @LHWizard *how* could there be zombie records? They were deleted on all nodes, as the consistency level is `ALL`.

Comment: when you do the delete, tombstones will be created. as you know, they stay in the SSTables until gc_grace_seconds have elapsed then they can be removed during compaction. what if, for example, one of your nodes is offline (network error, OOM, whatever) during compaction? As I understand the process, it will still have tombstones and when it comes back online, it will [replicate those tombstones to the rest of the cluster](https://academy.datastax.com/courses/ds201-cassandra-core-concepts/compaction-compaction-and-tombstones). Perhaps someone else can add more clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never say never, but it seems possible that you could do that.  You'd be sacrificing the high availability of being able to do deletes when some of the nodes are down or when there is network congestion, so operationally it might be a headache since nodes inevitably have downtime.  Probably that approach is only practical for very small clusters connected on a LAN.

One case you might have to consider is what would happen if an operator decided to restore a snapshot of a table.  That might resurrect some data you had deleted with ALL after the snapshot was taken.

You might want to cover yourself by using a TTL so that if you miss a delete, the data will eventually time out on its own.

I've sometimes thought C* should have an option to drop tombstones if all replicas have ack'd a delete.  Keeping them around unconditionally for ten days seems like overkill.